# Need DIV WRAPPER to match the size of the echo result

Tags: html, forms, echo, wrapper

I need to echo a field on my page.  I wrapped it in a DIV and I need the height of the DIV to match the height of the echo result.

How do i do this?

Right now the echo result goes past the DIV wrapper.  The DiV Wraper does not flow in height but comes short with the echo

```
<div id="vr_result"><?php echo $result->message ?></div>
```

Here is a picture:

[image: Sample image]

Comment: It looks like your div is inside of a table?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is if you added a height to the div with css, else the divs height should increase with the content unless it is floated.

Answer (score 0):

set this div block has min-height. for example  #bloc{min-height:40px}